# Volunteer Report Error: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: civivolunteer, reports

I'm trying to run a volunteer report on CiviCRM 5.5.2 on WordPress, and if I go to Reports -> Contact Reports -> Volunteer Reports, then click "Refresh Results" (no matter what criteria I seem to choose), I get the following error:

```
[nativecode=1055 ** Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bitnami_wordpress.civicrm_contact_assignee_civireport.sort_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]
```

The full log entry is pretty long but here's the group by clause (through to the end of the query, right before the error above appears in the log):

```
GROUP BY activity_civireport.id  ORDER BY civicrm_contact_assignee_civireport.sort_name ASC  LIMIT 0, 50
```

In case this sheds any light on things, I'm pretty new to CiviCRM and I set up a project, then starting logging hours, but the people for whom I'm logging hours are NOT on the volunteer roster for the project. Not sure if that matters or not but thought I'd mention it since maybe that's not how you're supposed to do things.

I can provide more details or the full error as needed. Thanks for any ideas anyone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you must be aware CiviVolunteer is not fully tested for 5.5.x version of CiviCRM. The last [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer) version was released for 5.0. This error usually occur when sql_mode for mysql is configured for only_full_group_by. I have just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/481) for this fix.

You can either apply the patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/481.patch) or [turn off only_full_group_by sql mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into those fixes and be more cognizant of the CiviCRM to CiviVolunteer compatibility recommendations. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the PR pradeep.

I think we will have an official release containing CiviCRM 5.x support bug-fixes this month. There are already some in the master branch on GitHub.